# user defined function in excel works in VBA and returns #value error in worksheet

Tags: vba, excel

I have designed a UDF to get the average sales of a product without the promotion period. 
The way it should work that it replaces the values of sales in promotion period with `""` and then get the average of sales. 
Note that: the same product may have one or more promotional period 
It works well when called in VBA or by MsgBox, but returns `#Value` in the worksheet

```
Public Function promless(itemcode As Range, daterange As Range, salesvalues As Range) As Double

 Application.Volatile

'find promotion rows

Dim porrange1 As Range
Dim pormotionrow() As Long
ReDim pormotionrow(1 To 10)
Dim code As String
code = itemcode.Value


   Set porrange1 = Sheets("por").Range("a:a").Find(code)
  pormotionrow(1) = porrange1.Row

If Not pormotionrow(1) = 0 Then
  For n = 2 To 10
   pormotionrow(n) = Sheets("por").Range("a:a").FindNext(porrange1).Row
   If pormotionrow(n) = pormotionrow(n - 1) Then
     pormotionrow(n) = 0
     Exit For
   End If
  Next
End If
Size = n - 1
ReDim Preserve pormotionrow(1 To Size)
'-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
'put sart and end of promotions
Dim porstart(), porend() As Variant
ReDim porstart(1 To Size)
ReDim porend(1 To Size)

For n = 1 To Size
  porstart(n) = Sheets("por").Range("c" & pormotionrow(n)).Value
Next

For n = 1 To Size
  porend(n) = Sheets("por").Range("d" & pormotionrow(n)).Value
Next
'--------------------------------------------------------------
'get data range date and apply pormotion conditions

Dim daterangearr As Variant
daterangearr = daterange.Value

For n = 1 To daterange.Columns.Count
  For i = 1 To Size
    If daterangearr(1, n) >= porstart(i) And daterangearr(1, n) <= porend(i) Then
     daterangearr(1, n) = "por"
    End If
  Next
Next

'----------------------------------------------------------------
'get sales values

Dim salesvaluesarr As Variant
salesvaluesarr = salesvalues.Value

'check if the date range is the same size of sales values
If salesvalues.Columns.Count <> daterange.Columns.Count Then
  MsgBox ("date range must be same number of sales values")
End If

'empty sales values that are in pormotion
For n = 1 To salesvalues.Columns.Count
  If daterangearr(1, n) = "por" Then salesvaluesarr(1, n) = Empty
Next
promless = Application.WorksheetFunction.Average(salesvaluesarr)

 End Function
```

In then worksheet for which I have the promotion information:

[image: pormotion sheet]

and the original sheet contains the sales data:

[image: data sheet]

Comment: Haven't examined in details, but that seems like a *lot* of code for a *function*. There are a number of things a UDF cannot do, like modifying other cells, or changing application state. See if invoking it from a *macro* wouldn't be more efficient than trying to use it as a UDF.

Comment: i don't see where you set the "daterange"

Comment: It's passed in as an argument.  You weren't clear about running it in VBA or where you put the msgBox.  If it has worked correctly then I am guessing that when in the code you are losing focus on the worksheet or the workbook.  So pass the sheet in as well and use that reference.  Always try and set things up in your calling code such as ThisWorkbook (refers to the workbook in that vba project and Worksheets("nameofsheet").  for example: Dim myWS as Worksheet and Set myWS = Thisworkbook.Worksheets("mySheetName") and pass it in as an arg to your receivingsub as (byVal myWSsub as Worksheet)

Comment: your SS does not show where the #Value appears, are you passing something back to a formatted column such as date that is a mismatch in type?  Handling dates is a mind on task.

Comment: @GMalc59 it is in the arrguments of the function as range

Comment: @Wookies-Will-Code it worked when i use it as a macro with fixed inputs for ranges

Comment: @Wookies-Will-Code i revised the code i only refered to one worksheet the por sheet Set porrange1 = Sheets("por").Range("a:a").Find(code)

Comment: @Wookies-Will-Code i have tried the function a blank sheet and it didn't work

Comment: @Wookies-Will-Code it works when i use the following msgbox statement:MsgBox promless(Range("a2"), Range("D1:cp1"), Range("d2:cp2"))